# How to not allow variables to be negative?

Tags: batch-file

I decided to mess around and make a batch game and I am using money as a currency, and I have a shop. It currently lets you buy the items without out having said money, but it makes it into the negatives. (Note: I am most likely overthinking this.)

Example: *Sword 30$,  You 0$ (buy item) You -30$*

This is what I am using:

```
set /a money=%money% -30
```

Comment: What DOS / Win are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If %money% lss 30 Echo Not enough dolleros
```

See second screen of help for `if`. `If /?`.

```
If %money% lss 30 (
    Echo Not enough dolleros 
) Else (
    Echo Gimme your cash, Jack
)
```